# @CreatedBy and @CreatedDate are null when updating entity

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, audit

I have a Spring Boot project using JPA, which is using auditing to set creation and modified data. It works fine when creating an entity, but when updating, the returned updated entity never fills the creation fields.
I even created a new project with nothing but controller and jpa repository and it seems there is a small piece of missing configuration.

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
class AuditConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun auditorProvider(): AuditorAware<String> {
        return TokenSubExtractor()
    }
}

class TokenSubExtractor: AuditorAware<String> {
    override fun getCurrentAuditor(): Optional<String> {
        //for simplicity
        return Optional.of("mail@project.com")
    }
}
```

Then, I have the entity and the auditable abstract class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "application", schema = "public")
data class Application(
    @Id @Column val id: UUID,
    @Column val name: String
): Auditable()

@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
abstract class Auditable {
    @CreatedBy
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    lateinit var createdBy: String

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    lateinit var creationDatetime: Instant

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column
    lateinit var lastModifiedBy: String

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column
    lateinit var lastModifiedDate: Instant
}
```

So when creating, all fields from `Auditable` class are filled. But when updating, only `lastModifiedBy` and `lastModifiedDate` are filled.
Both non nullable `createdBy` and `creationDatetime` are not retrieved by `repository.saveAndFlush(application)`.

When looking at the database table, with or without `@Transactional` annotation, the modified data is persisted. But when mapping the result, the creation data is null and throws the error `Could not write JSON: lateinit property createdBy has not been initialized`.

I have followed many articles and could not find what is the problem.
Answers in Java are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check below code, creationDate and creationBy not update when updating

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/auditing/AuditingHandlerSupport.java

```
   private void touchAuditor(Auditor auditor, AuditableBeanWrapper<?> wrapper, boolean isNew) {
        if (auditor.isPresent()) {
            Assert.notNull(wrapper, "AuditableBeanWrapper must not be null");
            if (isNew) {
                wrapper.setCreatedBy(auditor.getValue());
            }

            if (!isNew || this.modifyOnCreation) {
                wrapper.setLastModifiedBy(auditor.getValue());
            }

        }
    }

    private Optional<TemporalAccessor> touchDate(AuditableBeanWrapper<?> wrapper, boolean isNew) {
        Assert.notNull(wrapper, "AuditableBeanWrapper must not be null");
        Optional<TemporalAccessor> now = this.dateTimeProvider.getNow();
        Assert.notNull(now, () -> {
            return String.format("Now must not be null Returned by: %s", this.dateTimeProvider.getClass());
        });
        now.filter((__) -> {
            return isNew;
        }).ifPresent(wrapper::setCreatedDate);
        now.filter((__) -> {
            return !isNew || this.modifyOnCreation;
        }).ifPresent(wrapper::setLastModifiedDate);
        return now;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Checking `AuditingHandlerSupport` now is clear that `@CreatedBy` and `@CreatedDate` are not filled, like ever. I'll try to intercept these data and add them using the JPA Entity life cycle or figure out another solution.